# Converting C# date-time function to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I have an application in which I use a couple of date/time manipulation function to populate a couple of calendars. Basically, a user selects a month/year from a dropdown (say, March 2019) and I populate the calendars with 03/01/2019 and 03/31/2019.

I wanted to do this client side so tried to convert those function to javascript and I am getting strange results and can't see what I am doing wrong.

This is the original C# functions I defined and used:

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime dt)
{
    return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
}

public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime dtFirstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
    DateTime dtLastDayOfMonth = dtFirstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    return dtLastDayOfMonth;
}
```

I called these like below:

```
DateTime dtSelected = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(int.Parse(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)).AddYears(-1);
dtStartDate = Utils.FirstDayOfMonth(dtSelected);
dtEndDate = Utils.LastDayOfMonth(dtSelected);
```

The dropdown list is populated like:

```
for (int i = 12; i >= 1; i--)
{
    string s = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i).ToString("Y");
    ListItem li = new ListItem(s, i.ToString());
    ddlMonth.Items.Add(li);
}
```

The dropdown entries would look like:

```
May, 2019    -- value of 12
April, 2019  -- value of 11
....
July, 2018   -- value of 2
June, 2018   -- value of 1
```

This is my attempt at translating to javacript:

```
function firstDayOfMonth(dt) {debugger
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var month = dt.getMonth();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    return new Date(year, month, 1);
}

function lastDayOfMonth(dt) {debugger
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var month = dt.getMonth();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 1);
    var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1); --> shows error when called; Object doesn't support property or method 'AddMonths'

    return lastDayOfMonth;
}

$(document).on('change', '#ddlMonth', function () {debugger
    var monthID = this.value;
    var ddlMonth = $('#ddlMonth');
    var today = new Date();
    var startDate = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date();
    var dtSelected = new Date();

    if (ddlMonth.val() == "")
    {
        ....
    }
    else
    {debugger
        dtSelected.setMonth(dtSelected.getMonth() + ddlMonth.val() + 1); -- this becomes "Wed Oct 12, 2360" if I select "March, 2019" from dropdown!
        dtSelected.setFullYear(dtSelected.getFullYear() - 1);
        dtStartDate = firstDayOfMonth(dtSelected);
        dtEndDate = lastDayOfMonth(dtSelected);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the strange results?  There are three different types DateTime objects 1) Window starting at 1/1/1 2) Window starting at 1/1/1900 3) Unix starting at 1/1/1970

Comment: When I select "March, 2019" that has a value of 10, in "else" section after first statement is executed (e.g. .setMonth) it shows dtSelected as "Wed Oct 12 2360 18:57:37: (the time is correct), the next statement shows it as "Mon Oct 01 2359", the next one (e.g. firstDayOfMonth()) shows as Thu Oct 01, 2359" and when it tries to execute lastDayOfMonth, "var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths..." shows "Object doesn't support property or method 'AddMonths'

Comment: The new code has instruction new Date() get the default date in Java while original code populated with current date.  It looks like you now have a working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some problem in your code, this for example:

```
dtSelected.setMonth(dtSelected.getMonth() + ddlMonth.val() + 1); -- this becomes August of 2036!
```

you take today's month which is the 5 then add to itsome value from your slect and add 1 more and this is a lot of monthes to add.

I think you need to changesome things and do this like this:
change the select values to be the date of the first day of each month and not just number:

```
for (int i = 12; i >= 1; i--)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i);
    ListItem li = new ListItem(date.ToString("Y"), date.ToString("yyyy-MM-01"));
    ddlMonth.Items.Add(li);
}
```

in this format you can use it on js with no problem.

now for your js function:

```
function lastDayOfMonth(dt) {debugger
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var month = dt.getMonth();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 1);
    lastDayOfMonth.setMonth(lastDayOfMonth.getMonth() + 1);
    lastDayOfMonth.setDate(lastDayOfMonth.getDate() - 1);

    return lastDayOfMonth;
}

$(document).on('change', '#ddlMonth', function () {debugger
    var ddlMonth = $('#ddlMonth');
    dtStartDate = new Date(ddlMonth.val());
    dtEndDate = lastDayOfMonth(dtStartDate);
 }
```

Comment: For some reason, when I selected Marc 2019 (which now has the value of "2019-03-01" using your suggestion), startDate = new Date(ddlMonth.val()) returns "Thu Feb 28 2019". Then lastDayOfMonth also eturns the same date,, which is correct actually.

Comment: it worked when I changed the date format in drop down from 'yyyy-MM-01" to "MM-01-yyyy".